# How to use clojure hierarchies?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to understand how Clojure hierarchies work, with the **derive** and **is-a?** constructs. I'm not sure how I would use these with the maps and records in my program. Has anyone used these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your question a bit vague. Have you read the documentation on the Clojure website?

http://clojure.org/multimethods

I find the examples there quite easy to follow:

```
user=> ::rect
:user/rect
user=> (derive ::rect ::shape)
nil
user=> (parents ::rect)
#{:user/shape}
user=> (derive ::square ::rect)
nil
user=> (ancestors ::square)
#{:user/shape :user/rect}
user=> (isa? ::square ::shape)
true
```

There's also this blog post with a more "real-world" example:

http://www.prodevtips.com/2010/06/20/clojure-inheritance/

Comment: Thanks, useful information, so if I understand correctly if I have a record like (defrecord R []) and I want to put it in a type hieracrhy then I need to associate types with it, like (def r (R.)) (assoc r :type ::type). Is this correct?

Comment: Tbh, I've never done anything like this with records (unfortunately I didn't have the time to really dive into Clojure 1.2 yet), but it seems reasonable.